# Teaching kids how to turn off

Tags: behavior, primary-schooler

I had struggled most of my life and I do not know how to turn it off. e.g. I work 9-5 when I come home either I watch tv with food or go out shopping and when I am back or am free I am on the laptop again.

I can see the same trend at almost 7 years old. He keeps on watching tv until he is told to go to sleep or on holiday it is tv all day.

How can I teach my son to turn off and enjoy life and segment things to a time?

Comment: Remember what folks have told you previously: children copy parents. If you act like that, of course your son will copy you. Try changing your behaviour.

Comment: @RoryAlsop now question becomes how do I turn off and what to do because I do not know what to do beside sitting on laptop

Comment: "How to Break Up with Your Phone: The 30-Day Plan to Take Back Your Life" by Catherine Price might be a good starting point for a book recommendation

Comment: Or "The Power of Fun" by the same author

Comment: Kill two birds with one stone: play with your kids, read great stories to them (well, the little one might play on the floor while you do so), teach your son card games and board games, build lego villages together (or whatever he would enjoy), sooo many things to try!

Comment: @localhost If the reason you can't "turn off" is because you're tired after work and it's a low effort activity, find another low effort activity. Reading could be one. SInce I started that I lost some respect for people who talk about how many books they read since I've discovered that reading is an incredibly low effort activity on par with watching TV.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to turn off your son, you need to turn yourself off. Your son will do what you do without boundaries.

Start by understanding your son. You can try to ease him into trying something new by discouraging TV watching and encouraging other activities; worst case scenario, just get rid of the TV entirely (at least for a few days). Once you understand your son and his interests, you can try to build off of them. If he's interested in cars, spend the time you'd normally spend on the TV building a massive racetrack, or if he's interested in construction, build a Lego set.

The point here is to engage yourself and him in a way that is beneficial for everyone involved.